# Pass additional attributes to simple_form "as" option,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my application I  have form:

```
.row
  = simple_form_for @post, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form do |f|
    = f.error_notification
    .col-md-8
      = f.input :text, as: :prepend
      = f.input :active
    = f.button :submit
```

and custom input:

```
class PrependInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    template.content_tag(:div, class: 'col-md-12') do
      template.content_tag(:div, class: 'input-group') do
        template.concat cal_addon
        template.concat @builder.text_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)
      end
    end
  end

  def cal_icon
    "<i class=\"fa fa-calendar\"></i>".html_safe
  end

  def cal_addon
    template.content_tag(:span, class: 'input-group-addon') do
      template.concat cal_icon
    end
  end

  def input_html_options
    {class: 'form-control datepicker margin-top-none'}
  end

end
```

Now I want to pass additional attributes to this option "as" and use them in this custom input, is there any possibility to do this thing?